# Python: How do I disallow imports of a class from a module?

Tags: python, import, python-module, python-import

I tried:

```
__all__ = ['SpamPublicClass']
```

But, of course that's just for:

```
from spammodule import *
```

Is there a way to block importing of a class. I'm worried about confusion on the API level of my code that somebody will write:

```
from spammodule import SimilarSpamClass
```

and it'll cause debugging mayhem.

Comment: "I'm worried about confusion..." I'd focus on clear documentation rather than "prevention".  They can read the source.  They can bypass anything you put in place.  I think an ounce of clear documentation beats a pound of attempted "blocking".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The convention is to use a  _ as a prefix:

```
class PublicClass(object):
    pass

class _PrivateClass(object):
    pass
```

The following:

```
from module import *
```

Will not import the _PrivateClass.

But this will not prevent them from importing it. They could still import it explicitly.

```
from module import _PrivateClass
```

Comment: Thanks. That helps. One other problem is that I am importing a class from module B into module A as well (that I don't want users of module A to access, but it because immediately available upon importing it from module B.

Comment: I suppose I could import it as `from moduleb import SpamClass as _SpamClass`

Answer (score 7):

Start the names of private classes with and underscore, so that it will be clear just by the name that it is not for public use. That will not actually prevent anybody from importing the class, but it shouldn't happen by accident. It's a well established convention that names starting with an underscore are "internal".

Comment: This is how to do it in Python.  Python is deliberately designed with a "consenting adults" development philosophy.  If someone wants to import `SimilarSpamClass` or `_SimilarSpamClass`, they can, with the caveat that you warned them.

Answer (score 6):

**There is no way to actually block access to the contents of a module** or the contents of a class for that matter in Python. **This sort of thing is handled by convention** name your class `_SimilarSpamClass` (with a leading underscore) to indicate to callers that this is an implementation detail of your module and not part of the published API.

To mark something as "private" in Python **properly document your public API** so other developers know how to use your module correctly and **follow the standard [naming conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)** so that users of your module easily notice when they have strayed from your API to your implementation.